# GTLQueryYouTube:queryForVideosListWithIdentifier:part: didn't do anything (Objective C )

Tags: ios, objective-c, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm trying to use the iOS-GTLYouTube library for displaying videos. So far this is what I've got:

```
    //Get the youtube video list
    GTLServiceYouTube *service = [[GTLServiceYouTube alloc] init];
    // Set the APIKey
    service.APIKey = @"APIKey";

    GTLQueryYouTube *query = [GTLQueryYouTube queryForVideosListWithIdentifier:[vidListIds copy] part:@"id,snippet"];
    GTLServiceTicket *ticket = [   service executeQuery:query
                                   completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket, id object, NSError *error)
                                   {
                                   // This callback block is run when the fetch completes
                                       if (error == nil)
                                       {
                                           GTLYouTubeVideoListResponse *products = object;
                                           // iteration of items and subscript access to items.
                                           for (GTLYouTubeVideo *item in products)
                                           {
                                               GTLYouTubeVideoSnippetThumbnails *thumbnails = item.snippet.thumbnails;
                                               [thumbnailMutableList addObject:thumbnails];

                                               NSLog(@"Title: %@", item.snippet.title);
                                           }
                                       }
                                       else
                                       {
                                           NSLog(@"Error: %@", error.description);
                                       }
                                }];
```

I don't know why but this code didn't seem to do anything. There's neither the "Title:" log nor the "Error" log. I know that it was done in a separate thread so it worked asynchronously. But I've waited for 1-2 minutes and still nothing is shown. Can anybody help me here? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind. In the NSMutableString *vidListIds I forgot to append a comma. Silly me. Thanks for reading though. Sorry for the false alarm. :)